# Where clauses: Grocery CRUD and CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter-2, grocery-crud

I have two tables that need to be linked: 'user' and 'dealer'. The relation table is 'user_dealer'.

I found using `$crud->set_relation_n_n()` works well for edit and add screens to restrict which records are **edited** and **added**, like this:

```
$crud->set_relation_n_n('Dealers', 'user_dealer', 'dealer', 'user_id', 'dealer_id', 'dealer', null, array('id' => $this->session->userdata('dealer_id')));
```

But for some reason, this does not work for the LIST grid.

I tried `$crud->where()` but this does not work, as it does not have the column from the relation table there.

Can anybody help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is not possible, so I had to write a custom model that extends the Grocery Crud model and do what I needed to do.